# Can we have Matrix of vectors in julia?

Tags: julia

Can we form a julia matrix whose elements are vectors? I have tried the following but it only formed a matrix of Int.

```
julia> [[1, 2] [2, 3]; [4, 5] [3, 5]]
4×2 Matrix{Int64}:
1  2
2  3
4  3
5  5
```

But I wanted `[1, 2]` to be the first element not `1`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
julia> [[[1, 2]] [[2, 3]]; [[4, 5]] [[3, 5]]]
2×2 Matrix{Vector{Int64}}:
 [1, 2]  [2, 3]
 [4, 5]  [3, 5]
```

another would be:

```
julia> reshape([[1, 2], [4, 5], [2, 3], [3, 5]], 2, 2)
2×2 Matrix{Vector{Int64}}:
 [1, 2]  [2, 3]
 [4, 5]  [3, 5]
```

but maybe there is some better solution.